# Aggregating/Grouping a set of rows/records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table say "sample" which saves a new record each five minutes. 
Users might ask for data collected for a specific sampling interval of say 10 min or 30 min or an hour.

Since I have a record every five minutes, when a user asks for data with a hour sample interval, I will have to club/group every 12 (60/5) records in to one record (already sorted based on the time-stamp), and the criteria could be either min/max/avg/last value.

I was trying to do this in Java once I fetch all the records, and am seeing pretty bad performance as I have to iterate through the collection multiple times, I have read of other alternatives like jAgg and lambdaj, but wanted to check if that's possible in SQL (MySQL) itself.

The sampling interval is dynamic and the aggregation function (min/max/avg/last) too is user provided.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in SQL, but you have to carefully construct the statement.  Here is an example by hour for all four aggregations:

```
select min(datetime) as datetime,
       min(val) as minval, max(val) as maxval, avg(val) as avgval,
       substring_index(group_concat(val order by datetime desc), ',', 1) as lastval
from table t
group by floor(to_seconds(datetime) / (60*60));
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but this means that we will just get a single record, as we are grouping by time, but if I have say 1200 records in my table, I should output the values (min/max/avg/last) for each 12 records out of 1200, and so, should get 100 records as output. Am I making sense ?

Comment: @Sandeep . . . Not really.  This will output one record per hour as written.  That seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: My bad, the column type isn't datetime but is BIG INT & is epochtime, that too in milli sec, so was only getting one row, realized now, thanks a ton Gordon !!